# How to domain setting for connect to non-host domain?

Tags: dns

I want type domain.com at browser, then connect www.domain.com likes type google.com to connect www.google.com.

The information below is currently set.

```
domain.com. NS ns-1623.awsdns-10.co.uk. 
                  ns-1461.awsdns-54.org. 
                  ns-180.awsdns-22.com. 
                  ns-880.awsdns-46.net.

domain.com. SOA ns-1461.awsdns-54.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
*.domain.com. A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

What should I do if you would like to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use DNS redirection with a `CNAME` entry/record.  Check out [this link](http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/domain+names/dns/cname-records/).

Basically, you create a record that refers to some other A record (or, perhaps, another CNAME in some circumstances).  You can set this up for any number of subdomains (www, www2, mail, home, etc.).